# Angular DataBinding is not working in xmd-step label

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I am facing a peculiar problem! We are using [xmd-wizard](https://github.com/oscar09/xmdWizard) for the HTML page and in controller we are doing some operations. We are also translating the label field according to the configured language. So the code is -

```
<xmd-wizard active-step="currentStep" on-change="stepChanged()" on-save="savePath()">
<xmd-step label="{{translateData.GENERAL_INFORMATION}}" xmd-required="true">
```

But the DataBinding is not working over here! It's working in other place in the same HTML, for example -

```
<md-input-container flex="50" >
<label class="crudLabel">{{translateData.PATH}} {{translateData.NAME}}</label>
</md-input-container>
```

But only within the label element of xmd-step, the DataBinding is not working!!!
Has anyone faced this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was a known defect with the xmdWizard. I contacted the github owner at [github](https://github.com/oscar09/xmdWizard) and he has provided me the fix. So we should use the latest build of xmdWizard.

Hence I am closing this issue.
Thanks.